# fatal-error-unsupported-operand-types,I Keep getting the following error and I was wondering on how to fix it

Tags: php

I Keep getting the following error and I was wondering on how to fix it?

```
fatal-error-unsupported-operand-types error occurs
```

Please any one help me out:

```
if($_REQUEST['cityCode'] != ''){ 
    $_SESSION['Cri_locations'] = $_REQUEST["s"];
    $_SESSION['Cri_DateFrom'] = $_REQUEST["startDate"];
    $_SESSION['Cri_DateTo'] = $_REQUEST["endDate"];
    $what_to_search_id =str_replace("AREA-","",$_REQUEST["cityCode"]);
    $total_adults =0;
    $total_childs =0;
    $child_ages =0;
    $no_of_room =0;
    for($i=1;$i<=$_REQUEST["Cri_noofRooms"];$i++){ 
        $check_adults =$_REQUEST['adults-r'.$i.''];
        if($check_adults>0){
          $adults =$_REQUEST['adults-r'.$i.''];
          $childs =$_REQUEST['childs-r'.$i.''];
          $childAge =$_REQUEST['childAge-r'.$i.''];
          $packs_arr[] =array('adults'=>$adults,'childs'=>$childs,'childAge'=>$childAge);
          $total_adults =$total_adults+$adults;
          $total_childs =$total_childs+$childs;
          $child_ages =$child_ages+$childAge;//fatal-error-unsupported-operand-types accours here pls help 
          $no_of_room =$no_of_room+1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `print_r($childAge);` show inside your loop? And also `print_r($child_ages);`

Comment: Why concatenate an empty string on to the array index? `$_REQUEST['adults-r'.$i]` would work fine.

Comment: then how could i can get the value of $child_ages? even if i would have print the child_ages also... how could it will get the original value...cause where as i hv assinged the $child_ages = 0.

Comment: any one help me out pls